# Replace video track in MKV with track from .h264

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-editing, h.264, matroska

I want to replace only the video part in my existing mkv file with the video.h264 file I created externally, I don't want to interfere with other parts or features in my mkv file such as audio or subtitles. I wonder if there is an easy way to do this with mkvmerge. Otherwise I have to do a very laborious process.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ffmpeg to do this.

Not tested but off the top of my head:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i video.h264 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:s -c:s copy -map 1:v -c:v copy output.mkv
```

Should copy all audio and subtitles from the 1st file (first -i command), and then video from the second.

All codecs are set to `copy` so there is no conversion or transcoding, so the command should be as quick as your hard disk allows.

Comment: Yes, that actually makes a lot of sense, I'll try it right away

Comment: If you have trouble then give me a shout and I'll double check the command. As I say it was off the top of my head so not verified.

Comment: This really worked, and it was a very logical choice to use ffmpeg. Thank you very much... +1